# Insert string number that start with zero into string column using ContentValues, but leading zero is always removed

Tags: java, android, sqlite

My table was created with

```
db.execSQL(
    "CREATE TABLE periods (" +
    "  vehicle_id INTEGER KEY," +
    "  line_id INTEGER KEY," +
    "  period_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
    "  line_code STRING," +
    "  sup_code STRING," +
    "  start_date INTEGER," +
    "  end_date INTEGER" +
    ")"
);
```

And data was inserted with

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("vehicle_id", 1);
values.put("line_id", 2);
values.put("line_code", "0406");
values.put("sup_code", " ");
values.put("start_date", 1);
values.put("end_date", 24);
db.insert("periods", null, values);
```

But when when I retrieve data with

```
Cursor cPeriods = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM periods WHERE vehicle_id=" + vehicleId, null);
System.err.printf("SQLite: ### Get line_code = \"%s\"\n", cPeriods.getString(3));
```

The result always be "406"

How to fix this problem?
I don't want to do an ugly fix such as put some symbol in front of "0406" before insert and removed it out after retrieved.

Comment: Can you use the SQLite CLI tool to see whether the leading 0 got stored in the database?

Comment: @chrylis I just tried it and it doesn't.

Comment: @chrylis `TEXT` as a datatype works.

Answer (score 3):

`STRING` is not a valid SQLite type, so `line_code` is using the default type, `INTEGER` - try changing your `CREATE TABLE` statement to use the `TEXT` type in place of `STRING`.

Answer (score 1):

you should investigate the sql register part, if the line code is registered as a integer type, the zero will be deleted.